# Individual question filter possible?

Tags: support, filtering, tag-filters

is it possible at stack overflow to setup individual filter?

like:
filter for question with tag1, tag2, no answers, older then xx weeks / newer then xx weeks.

Reason: I was checking posts with tagged, but was looking if I can find unanswered posts where I could help with an answer. But use a tag only means LOTS of pagination...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already there.

See [our search tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Your example would be the search `[tag1] [tag2] answers:0`.

You can't search by date, though the `views:xyz` modifier may be useful. You may want to make the "date created/modifed" search operator a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 1):

Click on [`Unanswered`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) (near the ask question button) and then search for your tag(s).

A question is considered unanswered if it has no answer that has been upvoted or accepted. From there you can also click the 'no answer' tab, which gives the same result as using the search options @Manishearth describes [in another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131358/150909).